# ¿Cómo añadir una clave foránea en MYSQL? Me da error

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

Estoy empezando a crear tablas sencillas en MariaDB con XAMPP pero al intentar añadir una Foreing Key me da un error. He trasteado mucho, tanto con cosas de internet como con los apuntes de mi profesor, pero siempre me da el mismo error. Este es: "you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual..." He intentado utilizar ALTER TABLE, y también copiar el ejemplo de los apuntes:

```sql
CREATE TABLE alquiler(
dni VARCHAR2(9) CONSTRAINT dni_fk REFERENCES clientes(dni),
cod_pelicula NUMBER(5) CONSTRAINT pelicula_fk REFERENCES peliculas(cod),
CONSTRAINT alquiler_pk PRIMARY KEY(dni, cod_pelicula));
```

Las tablas que tengo son:

```sql
CREATE TABLE proveedores (
DNI varchar(9) PRIMARY KEY,
Nombre varchar(20),
ciudad varchar(20));

CREATE TABLE articulos(
cod_articulo varchar(7),
nombre varchar (10)
cantidad integer);
```

Quiero enlazar el cod_articulo de la tabla artículos con el nombre de la tabla proveedores. Las tablas se crean sin problema.

Espero que me podáis ayudar y haberme explicado bien, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola. Pulsa en [edit] y añade los CREATE TABLE de todas las tablas implicadas.

Comment: cod_pelicula???? alquiler??? que tiene que ver una cosa con la otra?

Comment: Lo he puesto arriba, es el ejemplo que aparece en los apuntes del profesor.

Comment: Es posible que estés definiendo tus Constraints antes de las tablas a las cuales haces las referencias, verifica eso.

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas:

1. Cuando declaras llaves foráneas, las tablas a las que refieren esas llaves deben estar puestas primero en el orden de los `CREATE TABLE`, de lo contrario cuando intentes crear esas referencias las tablas no existirán y el código fallará. Por ejemplo, antes de crear `alquiler` debes haber creado las tablas `clientes` y `peliculas`
2. Para declarar llaves foráneas, en vez de usar `CONSTRAINT`, usa directamente `FOREIGN KEY` seguido del nombre de la restricción y de la columna entre paréntesis. Verifica que te conviene usar las reglas de integridad referencial por defecto, pues no declaras nada al respecto explícitamente. [Revisa la documentación al respecto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).
3. Para declarar la llave primaria lo mismo, puedes poner simplemente `PRIMARY KEY`, seguido del nombre y de la columna entre paréntesis.
4. No existe un tipo de dato `NUMBER` en MySQL, revisa aquí los [tipos numéricos en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html).
5. Convendría también que especifiques el tipo de engine en que se deben construir tus tablas, no dejes nada al azar, porque las tablas en ese caso se crearan con el engine que haya sido definido por defecto.

Aquí te dejo un código funcionando. Faltaba la tabla `peliculas`, he creado una con lo mínimo. Para futuras preguntas, pon un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable que incluya todas las tablas, y si lo pones en un fiddle, mejor aún.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE proveedores (
  `dni` varchar(9) PRIMARY KEY,
  `nombre` varchar(20),
  `ciudad` varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE clientes (
  `dni` varchar(9) PRIMARY KEY,
  `nombre` varchar(20),
  `ciudad` varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE peliculas (
  `cod` INT(5) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE articulos(
  `cod_articulo` varchar(7),
  `nombre` varchar(10),
  `cantidad` integer
);

CREATE TABLE alquiler(
 `dni` varchar(9), 
  `cod_pelicula` int(5),
  FOREIGN KEY `dni_fk` (`dni`) REFERENCES `clientes` (`dni`),
  FOREIGN KEY `pelicula_fk` (`cod_pelicula`) REFERENCES `peliculas` (`cod`),
  PRIMARY KEY `alquiler_pk` (`dni`, `cod_pelicula`)
);
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hx6hy2Y2PeswEoeft4SK1n/1)